# Angular $filter is filtering negative numbers even though the filter is a positive number

Tags: angularjs, filter, negative-number

I have a simple filter for a array. each item in the array has a 'Rating' attribute that is a number. The values can be -3,-2,-1,1,2,3.

If I do

`$scope.ratingFilter = -3; // negative numbers work fine`

BUT if I do

`$scope.ratingFilter = 3; // positive numbers are showing items that have a Rating of 3 AND -3. Why are negative number appearing in the filter???`

```
$scope.updateMarkers = function(){

    var filters = [];
    if($scope.ratingFilter != 'all'){
        filters.Rating = $scope.ratingFilter;
    }

    var arr = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.allMarkers, function(value, key){
        arr.push(value);
    });

    $scope.markers = $filter('filter')(arr, filters);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a string filter?

Comment: @FrankModica Hmmm, I'm not sure what you mean. Rating attribute in the arr array is a number not a string. I'll check what $scope.ratingFilter is but I'm sure it's a number.

Comment: I mean the filter provided by AngularJS - it might be returning anything that contains 3. Try adding another number that has a 3 in it and see if it returns that too.

Comment: @FrankModica
`console.log(angular.isString($scope.ratingFilter));` returns false so it is a number.

Comment: @FrankModica ok... i just did $scope.ratingFilter = 43; and that returned 0 results so it's not a partial match. Whats strange is that -1,-2,-3 all work and you would think that if it was any number with 3 that it would also return all the positive 3's. very strange.

Comment: I mean add 43 to your list, with your filter kept as 3

Comment: @FrankModica yes you are right. If I change my array item to 43 and set the filter to 3... the 43 item displays. So how do I fix this? Thanks heaps for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider filtering the array yourself in the controller with plain JavaScript:

```
$scope.markers = arr.filter(x => x.Rating === ratingFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, see my answer below. Solved the issue for me.

Comment: @JamieBarker You're welcome. But I'm curious, why bring AngularJS in for this when it can be done with standard JS?

Comment: Yo Frank, It quite a massive app. 2+ years dev so far.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'strict' value to `true`in the `$filter`.

`$filter('filter')(arr, filters, true);`

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

$scope.dsset = $filter('filter')($scope.array, { id: 1});